# Diferença entre datas retorna zero em vez do total de segundos

Tags: python, datetime, data

Tenho este código que calcula a diferença entre duas datas:

```
import datetime as dt

natal = dt.date(2021, 12, 25)
reveillon = dt.date(2022, 1, 1)

print(reveillon - natal)
print((reveillon - natal).days)
print((reveillon - natal).seconds)
print((reveillon - natal).microseconds)
```

O resultado foi:

[image: resultado]

Ele disse que o `0` nos segundos e microssegundos foi porque ele usou `date`, e não `datetime`. Como ele não mostrou nenhum exemplo de como seria com o `datetime`, tentei por conta própria e fiz isso aqui:

```
natal = dt.datetime(2021, 12, 25, 11, 0, 0, 0)
reveillon = dt.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0)

print(reveillon - natal)
print((reveillon - natal).days)
print((reveillon - natal).seconds)
print((reveillon - natal).microseconds)
```

Dessa vez, o resultado foi:

[image: resultado]

Já estranhei um pouco, pois se são 7 dias de diferença entre as duas datas, como podem ser apenas 3599 segundos? Então, fui pro último teste:

```
natal = dt.datetime(2021, 12, 25, 12, 0, 0, 0)
reveillon = dt.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0)

print(reveillon - natal)
print((reveillon - natal).days)
print((reveillon - natal).seconds)
print((reveillon - natal).microseconds)
```

Dessa vez, o resultado foi o mesmo da primeira imagem. O que eu fiz de errado? Por que os zeros voltaram? Uma semana tem 604800 segundos, e não 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olhando a [documentação do módulo `datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html), podemos ver que a subtração de duas datas resulta em um `timedelta` (procure pelas tabelas indicadas por "*Supported operations*", como [esta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.day)).

E [segundo a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects), um `timedelta` tem as seguintes características:

> ***Only days, seconds and microseconds** are stored internally. Arguments are converted to those units:*
>
> - *A millisecond is converted to 1000 microseconds.*
> - *A minute is converted to 60 seconds.*
> - *An hour is converted to 3600 seconds.*
> - *A week is converted to 7 days.*
>
> *and days, seconds and microseconds are then normalized so that the representation is unique, with:*
>
> - *0 <= microseconds < 1000000*
> - *0 <= seconds < 3600*24 (the number of seconds in one day)*
> - *-999999999 <= days <= 999999999*

Em tradução livre:

> **Apenas dias, segundos e microssegundos** são armazenados internamente. Os argumentos são convertidos para estas unidades:
>
> - Um milissegundo é convertido para 1000 microssegundos.
> - Um minuto é convertido para 60 segundos.
> - Uma hora é convertida para 3600 segundos.
> - Uma semana é convertida para 7 dias.
>
> e depois os dias, segundos e microssegundos são normalizados para uma representação única, na qual:
>
> - 0 <= microseconds < 1000000
> - 0 <= seconds < 3600*24 (a quantidade de segundos em um dia)
> - -999999999 <= days <= 999999999

Ou seja, internamente um `timedelta` só guarda 3 campos: a quantidade de dias (`days`), a quantidade de segundos (`seconds`) e a quantidade de microssegundos (`microseconds`). Quaisquer outras quantidades de tempo são convertidas para uma dessas, e depois os valores são normalizados para que fiquem dentro da faixa de valores mínimos e máximos de cada um.

---

Para entender melhor, vamos ver alguns casos. Para estes testes, criei uma função que calcula a diferença entre duas datas e imprime os campos do `timedelta`:

```py
# esta função será usada nos próximos exemplos
def diff(start, end):
    t = end - start
    print(t, t.days, t.seconds, t.microseconds, sep='\n')
```

Primeiro vamos ver a diferença entre duas datas que possuem o mesmo dia, porém horários diferentes:

```py
from datetime import datetime

# mesmo dia, com 3 horas de diferença
diff(datetime(2021, 12, 25, 10, 0, 0, 0), datetime(2021, 12, 25, 13, 0, 0, 0))
```

As datas estão no mesmo dia, com 3 horas de diferença entre elas. O resultado é:

```
3:00:00
0
10800
0
```

Ou seja, a diferença de 3 horas foi normalizada para 10800 segundos.

Agora se eu mudar para que a diferença seja de 10 dias e 3 horas:

```py
from datetime import datetime

# diferença de 10 dias e 3 horas
diff(datetime(2021, 12, 15, 10, 0, 0, 0), datetime(2021, 12, 25, 13, 0, 0, 0))
```

A saída passa a ser:

```
10 days, 3:00:00
10
10800
0
```

Repare que os segundos ainda continuam sendo 10800. O que mudou foi apenas o campo `days`, que passou a ser 10. Esse é um detalhe importante, que é o que parece ter te confundido: o campo `seconds` **não** tem o total de segundos correspondente a 10 dias.

Na verdade ele tem a quantidade de segundos depois que os valores são normalizados (segundo as regras acima), lembrando que `seconds` não pode ser maior que `3600 * 24` (que é a quantidade de segundos em um dia). Então o `timedelta` acaba tendo o campo `days` com o valor 10 (indicando que são 10 dias), e o restante (as 3 horas, que não é suficiente para completar um dia) é convertido para segundos e microssegundos (como o valor em segundos dá exato, então `microseconds` é igual a zero).

---

## Sobre os seus exemplos

Ao contrário do que você afirmou nos seus testes, este código:

```py
import datetime as dt

natal = dt.datetime(2021, 12, 25, 11, 0, 0, 0)
reveillon = dt.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0)

print(reveillon - natal)
print((reveillon - natal).days)
print((reveillon - natal).seconds)
print((reveillon - natal).microseconds)
```

na verdade gera a seguinte saída:

```
7 days, 1:00:00
7
3600
0
```

Ou seja, uma diferença de sete dias e uma hora. No caso, o campo `days` é 7, e segundo as regras de normalização acima, a "uma hora" (que não é suficiente para completar um dia) é convertida para segundos, e por isso o campo `seconds` é 3600.

Novamente: o campo `seconds` **não** tem o total de segundos corresponde aos sete dias e uma hora. Os dias vão em um campo separado, e o que "sobra" é que vai para os segundos e microssegundos.

Aliás, é por isso que no seu último exemplo `seconds` é igual a zero, pois a diferença é de sete dias exatos, sem nenhum segundo a mais nem a menos. Por isso não há "excedente" e tanto `seconds` quanto `microseconds` acabam sendo zero.

---

Se quer o total de segundos, basta usar `total_seconds()`:

```py
import datetime as dt

natal = dt.datetime(2021, 12, 25, 11, 0, 0, 0)
reveillon = dt.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0)

diferenca = reveillon - natal

# days e seconds pegam os valores normalizados
print(diferenca.days) # 7
print(diferenca.seconds) # 3600

# total_seconds() devolve o total de segundos
print(diferenca.total_seconds()) # 608400.0
```

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado pela paciência, me ajudou muito com essa resposta! Ótima explicação!